# How to count mutiple columns occurrencies in whole table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 5 columns that has data which are ids from other table [image: Database table here]

how do I count how many times each number appears in whole table, in all records.
I want to count paslauga1, paslauga2, paslauga3, paslauga4, paslauga5 data occurrencies.
For example there is 2 records that has 4 times 1 id 2 times 2 id 1 time id 3
So I want it to output

```
1 has appeared 4 times
2 has appeared 1 times
3 has appeared 2 times
```

and if more ids would be there 4,5,6 etc it would display them too.

I need to count this so I can use it on php code, maybe theres easier way to do so in php?

Comment: You should really, really change your table design. Having numbers in column names is almost always a bad sign.

Comment: what are the ranges of numbers?

Comment: @Saeidsamadidana the 2nd table has services, so as many services I add, the more it will have numbers.

Comment: You're violating the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). This would be trivial if your data was structured in a proper relational form.

Comment: @Saeidsamadidana at the moment it is 3

Comment: You said 3 occurred 1 times but your example shows 3 times. I am confused. I mean what numbers each column accept?

Comment: @Saeidsamadidana Yes I made a mistake, 3 occurred 2 times, vizito_id should not be counted, only paslauga1, paslauga2, paslauga3, paslauga4, paslauga5 should be counted

Comment: @Mantas, the issue with your database design is that as you add more services, you need to add more columns. If you end up offing 100 services, you need 100 columns. If you stop offering service1, unless you want to delete all history of that service, you can't delete the column. As time goes on, you add more and more columns you can't remove. It is poor design to have to modify your table every single time you want to offer a new service. Ideally you would have another table lising all available services and another table that maps a visit to what services were rendered.

Comment: it is like that, I have table that holds bookings. Bookings ID goes to services_done table. services table holds services that company may offer you. After booking is done, the employee chooses from 1 to 5 services that was done. The services ID goes to services_done table, so no more columns are created, only records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT paslauga, count(paslauga)
FROM (
       SELECT paslauga1 as paslauga FROM yourTable
       UNION ALL
       SELECT paslauga2 as paslauga FROM yourTable
       UNION ALL
       SELECT paslauga3 as paslauga FROM yourTable
       UNION ALL
       SELECT paslauga4 as paslauga FROM yourTable
       UNION ALL
       SELECT paslauga5 as paslauga FROM yourTable
     ) T
GROUP BY paslauga
```

Comment: thank you, works flawlessly. By the way, it will count other numbers i.e. if I add number 4 and so on? and what is T letter?

Comment: Yes, as long you dont add more columns `paslauga#`  should work ok

Comment: how would I innerjoin another table on vizito_id?

Comment: Not sure what your question mean. You should include some example. But you probably should conider add another question.

Comment: I mean date information from other table which refernces to vizito_id column. I was using INNER JOIN to join it.

Comment: We usually need db schema, sample data and desire output to understand the problem. Include that in your question or in a new one and we can help you find a answer more quickly.

Comment: I'm also getting an empty line on first column paslauga which is after query is executed and in 2nd column which is count(paslauga) a number 3 or 2. what is this? and also what is T letter for?

Comment: Take a picture to show me your result. Consider [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) also maybe prepare a working sample in www.sqlfiddle.com  `T` is the alias for the subquery, so you can treat it like a normal table.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple loop in PHP that counts the numbers in an array.

```
$counts = array();
$result = $pdo->query("SELECT paslauga1, paslauga2, paslauga3, paslauga4, paslauga5 FROM yourTable");
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    foreach ($row as $col) {
        if ($col !=== null) {
            if (isset($counts[$col])) {
                $counts[$col]++;
            } else {
                $counts[$col] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
ksort($counts);
foreach ($counts as $id => $c) {
    echo "$id has appeared $c times<br>";
}
```

Comment: Im not really a php guy. So Im wondering, PHP can you assign array index without define the array size? And assing `$count[3]`  and later `$count[1]`  and leave `$count[2] =null`  ?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes. PHP arrays are associative arrays, they don't have to be declared.

Comment: @Mantas Did you initialize `$pdo` to a PDO object?

Comment: @Barmar I'm sorry but I don't even know what it is.

Comment: PDO and mysqli are the two common APIs for accessing MySQL from PHP. If you use `mysqli` that should be `mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT ...")` where `$conn` is the result of `mysqli_connect()`.

Comment: @Mantas You tagged the question with `php`, so I assumed you know how the basics of performing MySQL queries from PHP. I'm not going to hold your hand through the entire educational process.